# How to deploy laravel 5.4 to the production server?

Tags: laravel-5

I generate one laravel project . Now i need to move the project to the production server. In the local system, I use `php artisan serve` to run the project and run http://127.0.0.1:8000/ .

while moving to the production server, I changed the .env file

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://myserverip
```

My config/app.php

```
 'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://my ip'),
```

I run the project (ip/projectfolder) in live it displays dirctory files listing in the browser.
Is there is any thing extra I need to configure ?

Comment: Can you tell which web server you are using (Apache, nginx...)

Comment: @StatiX using Apache server

Comment: @StatiX  using Apache with ubuntu 16.04

Comment: have you installed `libapache2-mod-php` apache-php module? `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: @Nuwan  libapache2-mod-php installed

Comment: @SammuSundar try to navigate to your ./public directory from your browser.If it loads your app then you need to configure Apache virtual host file which should be pointed to the public directory

Comment: @Nuwan I naviagate to public folder. But not working it shows url domain/public/login. says error

Comment: @SammuSundar What it says in that error? I think you should test your apache php setup ..just create new directory with `index.php` file which has content `<?php echo 'test';`?>. Then navigate to that directory and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176628/discussion-between-sammu-sundar-and-nuwan).